# How to create a table with vertically sticky header and horizontally sticky first column using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, tabular

When displaying tabular data, I think that in some cases having an always visible header row and an always visible first column can really improve the readability and the overall usability of a table, especially if there is a lot of data in the table. The problem occurs when the table has to support both horizontal and vertical scrolling. A good example of such a table can be found from the NBA application when viewing box score of a past game. Here's an example image from the NBA Android application:
[Example table from NBA mobile application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qfAJ.jpg)

As you can clearly see from the image the header row is horizontally aligned with the actual table data and the first column is vertically aligned with the table data. I don't know whether or not it's an involuntary or a voluntary decision to prevent scrolling both horizontally and vertically with the same touch motion but that's a minor detail I don't care about.

I don't know how to implement this using Xamarin Forms. I am not interested in a closed source / paid solution since I would like to actually learn how to accomplish this by myself. I do realize that I most likely have to use custom renderers for both Android and IOS. My current idea is that I have an absolute layout where I have the following elements:

- The first cell (it's stationary and the only stationary thing)
- Rest of the header row inside a horizontal scrollview
- First column inside a listview/stacklayout + vertical scrollview
- The actual table data inside a listview + horizontal scrollview / stacklayout + horizontal and vertical scrollview

With this setup I would capture the touch event and send it to the other listviews/scrollviews, thus synchronizing the scrolling. In fact I can easily achieve the synchronized scrolling with the first column and the actual table data by setting the table data inside the same vertical scrollview as the first column. But I don't know how to synchronize the horizontal scrolling to the header row and I do believe that this can't be accomplished by clever component structure. I have tested only on Android so far that I can capture the touch event in a scrollview custom renderer's OnTouchEvent -method but I don't know how I could send this to the header row scrollview from the custom renderer.

Here is a draft XAML illustrating my approach.

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ScrollView
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        x:Name="HeaderScrollView"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Skip first column, leave it empty for stationary cell -->
            <Label Text="Column 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Text="Column 2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Label Text="Column 3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
            <Label Text="Column 4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        x:Name="FirstColumnScrollView"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,50,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
        BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Column1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
            <ScrollView
                x:Name="TableDataScrollView"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout
                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Column2}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Column3}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Column4}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Column5}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
    <Label Text="First Column" BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,200,50" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

As you can see the problem is that horizontal scrolling events between HeaderScrollView and TableDataScrollView are not shared and I don't know how to accomplish this in the best way possible or at all.

I do appreciate all the help and feedback with this!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview

Comment: @FreakyAli Is TableView supposed to be used for this kind of purpose? For example it is missing the ItemsSource option altogether and all the examples show some sort of a settings menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help with this @Harikrishnan and @Wendy Zang - MSFT ! The Zumero DataGrid inspired me to do the motion event handling differently from the usual motion event handling flow. I basically created the following custom renderer for the AbsoluteLayout

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Test.Droid;
using Test.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using View = Android.Views.View;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StatisticsTable), typeof(StatisticsTableRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
    public class StatisticsTableRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        private View _headerScrollView;
        private View _tableScrollView;
        private float _startX;
        public StatisticsTableRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (_headerScrollView == null || _tableScrollView == null)
            {
                // Completely dependant on the structure of XAML
                _headerScrollView = GetChildAt(0);
                _tableScrollView = GetChildAt(1);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                _startX = ev.GetX();
            }

            var headerScroll = false;
            if (_startX > _headerScrollView.GetX())
            {
                headerScroll = _headerScrollView.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            var tableScroll = _tableScrollView.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);


            return headerScroll || tableScroll;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I always intercept the motion event and then manually dispatch it to the children. However that was not enough. I had to prevent HeaderScrollView from scrolling when the motion event didn't start inside of it because the TableDataScrollView wouldn't scroll if the motion event wasn't started inside of it. I also had to create custom renderers for all scrollviews in this table. TableDataScrollView and HeaderScrollView were using the same custom renderer. The only thing that custom renderer implemented was OnInterceptTouchEvent like this:

```
public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    return false;
}
```

I am not quite sure why this is necessary but it seems to have done the trick for me. I suppose that sometimes the HeaderScrollView would intercept the motion event and this caused the header to scroll without scrolling of the table data.

The vertical scrollview aka FirstColumnScrollView in the question's XAML had to implement motion event handling differently because it is the parent of the TableDataScrollView and we are now handling motion events in a top-to-bottom manner instead of the default Android way of bottom-to-top. This caused issues where FirstColumnScrollView would simply handle the motion event and not pass it to TableDataScrollView which would then lead to the header and actual table data to be out of sync with each other. This is why I added the following custom renderer for it

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Test.Droid;
using Test.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using View = Android.Views.View;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ChildFirstScrollView), typeof(ChildFirstScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
    public class ChildFirstScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        private View _childView;
        public ChildFirstScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (_childView == null)
            {
                _childView = GetChildAt(0);
            }

            _childView.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this ScrollView we always intercept/handle the motion event and we always send it to the child ScrollView first before handling the motion event.

I also had to do some minor adjustments to the XAML shown in the question. I set the starting X of HeaderScrollView to the width of the first column so it doesn't actually go under the static header of the first column. However this caused issues because I was unable to use width of the AbsoluteLayout (Why is it so hard in XAML?) to calculate the correct width for the HeaderScrollView. Now the width was set in a way that a part of the HeaderScrollView will always be outside of the viewport causing the last header to be never shown. So I added a "PaddingColumn" to the header grid with a width equal to the first column. I also had to add a "PaddingRow" to the FirstColumnScrollView grid for the same reason.

One other thing I had to do was to set the spacing of the grid inside FirstColumnScrollView to 0. Without that, there was this small gap from where you could start motion events that would only scroll the header and not the table data.

This is only the Android solution at the moment but I'll come back with the iOS one if I can accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a DataGrid component with Frozen row and Frozen column feature. There are some third party components that would meet your requirements.

Syncfusion, Telerik and Infragistics DataGrids have the features you are looking for. Refer below links.

- https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-datagrid
- https://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/datagrid
- https://www.infragistics.com/products/xamarin/grids-and-lists/data-grid

There are few open-source DataGrid available as well. But not sure whether they have the row and column pinning features. Check the below links.

- https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/

Comment: Thanks for the help and I'm sorry that I forgot to specify that I am not looking for a closed source solution. I was aware that this can be achieved with these paid UI components but I want to learn how this can be accomplished and a paid component doesn't help with that. I'll edit the question accordingly. Also that open source solution didn't seem to support row or column pinning.

Comment: I could see that the below DataGrid component is free. You can debug the source code if you wish to explore the row pinning logic. Am basically from the custom component development background. All you need to do is to do apply some logic in layouting your views and play a bit with the binding of views that scroll. 

https://github.com/zumero/DataGrid#what-are-its-features

Comment: @kapseli: Hope that helps. If so, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For open source, you could use `Zumero DataGrid` for Xamarin.Forms. It supports scrolling, both horizontal and vertical, optional top frozen header row, optional left frozen column and so on. You could download the sample code form the link below.

Zumero DataGrid for Xamarin.Forms: https://github.com/zumero/DataGrid/tree/8caf4895e2cc4362da3dbdd4735b5c6eb1d2dec4

[image]

For the sample code, if you get the error below, run as admin would be okay.

```
Build action 'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's targets
```