# Xamarin Forms display data grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm a beginner with xamarin forms and i have to display dynamic data in grid form. My data has multiple columns and rows, which doesn't always fit the screen size. So i must scroll horizontal and vertical. The first column is a description of the data, I called it row header. My goal is to move/scroll the data "under" the columns and "under" the row header. The columns and the row header must always be visible.
Perhaps somebody had the same problem/solution and point me to the right direction? Or a sample?

**Additional info:**
To be clearer. The column header must scroll left, if the user scrolls the data area left. Because not all columns could display on screen. Same with the row header. It must scroll down, if user scrolls the data area down.
In excel the function is named "Freeze Panes":
[image: Excel sample]
My ugly powerpoint:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Android and iOS. On UWP it doesn't scroll smoothly. But thats not important for me:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="80" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Empty" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1"
Grid.Row="0"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
<ScrollView x:Name="colScrollView"
Orientation="Horizontal"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGoldenrodYellow">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Text="Column" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="Column" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
<Label Text="Column" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
<Label Text="Column" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
<Label Text="Column" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />
</Grid>
</ScrollView>
<BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
BackgroundColor="Transparent"></BoxView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="0"
Grid.Row="1"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<ScrollView x:Name="rowScrollView"
Orientation="Vertical"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

<Grid BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
</Grid>
</ScrollView>
<BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
BackgroundColor="Transparent"></BoxView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1"
Grid.Row="1"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<ScrollView x:Name="dataScrollView"
Orientation="Both"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />

<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />

<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" />

<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" />

<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" />
<Label Text="Cell" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" />
</Grid>
</ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public MyPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
dataScrollView.Scrolled += DataScrollView_Scrolled;
}

private async void DataScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
await rowScrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, e.ScrollY, false);
await colScrollView.ScrollToAsync(e.ScrollX, 0, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Grid** as the root layout and **ScrollView** to show data .

The ScrollView will scroll-able when the data are out of screen .

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!--Columns-->
<Label Text="title0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
<Label Text="title1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
<Label Text="title2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
<Label Text="title3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />


        <!--Row Header-->
<Label Text="title0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label Text="title7" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" />


 <!--Data-->




</Grid>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thing you misunderstood me. ;) I updated the question. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You could put the grid in a scroll view .

Comment: Is it ok to use third-party UI libraries or not?

Comment: I updated again. ;)  @Joseph: Perhaps. Depends on cost and functionality.

Comment: As I said , you could put the grid in a ScrollView .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Could you update your example? If i increment the cols, the text wraps to fit the screen width. So the scrolling not works.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thank you. But the first column is scrolling out of screen. Thats not what i want ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212795/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-saftpresse99).

Answer (score 0):

if you use xamarin.forms syncfusion datagrid (SfDataGrid) you have two options to solve this:

1)-the first by using the [Unbound Rows](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/unbound-row) and [Unbound Columns](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/unbound-column) feature of the SfDataGrid.

2)-second by using the [Freeze Panes](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/freeze-panes) (also called Frozen Views) feature of the SfDataGrid.

if it was to me i would go for the second option which is Freeze Panes , here is how it looks like:

[image]

syncfusion has a free community licence that you can use, the community licence keys can be generated once you open a free account in there [page](https://www.syncfusion.com/).

once you have the key follow the [setup instructions](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started) on how to setup the SfDataGrid, the SfDataGrid is just a small NuGet package.

then in your App class constractor past the key as a parameter for the RegisterLicense method.

```
public App()
{
    //Register Syncfusion license
    Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("YOUR LICENSE KEY");

    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new App1.MainPage();
}
```

for more on [licensing](https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/license-key#xamarinforms).

Comment: Thank you. I saw this component. But it's to expensive for our small project.

Comment: check this out it might be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128529/how-to-create-a-table-with-vertically-sticky-header-and-horizontally-sticky-firs/

Comment: check this helpful discussion:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96250/xamarin-forms-grid-display-with-frozen-columns

Comment: there is also this old post:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/670141/read-and-write-microsoft-excel-with-open-xml-sdk

Comment: another old blog post:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/generate-excel-spreadsheets-in-native-mobile-apps/

Comment: Thanks. This looks also interesting to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128529/how-to-create-a-table-with-vertically-sticky-header-and-horizontally-sticky-firs/