# Using Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid how to make the first column of a table fixed on horizontal scroll. Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid` and now I would like to
make the first column of a table fixed on horizontal scroll. Please see image.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image]

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"  SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfesstional}" RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" 
                                BorderColor="#CCCCCC"  HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" ActiveRowColor="#8899AA">
    <x:Arguments>
        <ListViewCachingStrategy>RetainElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
    </x:Arguments>
    <dg:DataGrid.HeaderFontSize>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>15</OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
        </OnIdiom>
    </dg:DataGrid.HeaderFontSize>
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
       
        <dg:DataGridColumn PropertyName="Name" Width="3*" >
            <dg:DataGridColumn.FormattedTitle>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="User Name" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </FormattedString>
                
            </dg:DataGridColumn.FormattedTitle>
        </dg:DataGridColumn>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="User Email" PropertyName="Email" Width="2*"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="User Phone" PropertyName="Number" Width="1*"/>

    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>

    <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
        <dg:PaletteCollection>
            <Color>#F2F2F2</Color>
            <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
        </dg:PaletteCollection>
    </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don’t see anything in the docs that would allow that.  It’s open source so you’re free to make your own mods

Comment: Are there any other options to achieve this? @Jason

Comment: I have no idea.  Look at the options available in other datagrid components.  SO is not a free research service.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to achieve the fixed column when scrolling horizontally.

**Approach 1:**

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191673/9644964), you could use the open source: [Zumero DataGrid](https://github.com/zumero/DataGrid/tree/8caf4895e2cc4362da3dbdd4735b5c6eb1d2dec4). It supports scrolling, both `horizontal` and `vertical`, optional top frozen header row, optional left frozen column and so on.

**Approach 2:**

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/issues/87), you could add a `ScrollView` out of the `DataGrid` and set the `Orientation="Both"` like below:

```
    <ScrollView Orientation="Both">
    <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam}"
                     RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8"
                     PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                    WidthRequest="600" 
                     ActiveRowColor="#8899AA">
```

Comment: I have do this.  But I would like to make the first column of a table fixed on horizontal scroll. Means all row of 0th column fixed during horizontally scroll and all row of 1st column will scroll horizontally. @Alexandar May-MSFT

Comment: I believe the first approach has met your requirement as the 0th column fixed during horizontally scroll and all row of 1st column will scroll horizontally. @Raj

Comment: I am trying approach 1 @Alexandar May-MSFT

Comment: May I confirm if you have adopted `Approach 1` ? If so, please mark it as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!